# BuildFire: how to link to Side Menu app sections from custom plugins?

Tags: javascript, html, buildfire

What I mean by "Side Menu app sections":

- User profile
- Login / logout
- Notifications
- App Settings
- App Content
- Home

These special app sections are available in the Side Menu, but I would like to be able to link to them from any custom plugin. Is there any way to be able to do this?

My unsuccessful attempt at injecting this code into a custom folder plugin's widget index.html:

```
<a class="padding-top-five" ng-click="openPage('appSettings');" onclick="clickFeedback(this);">
  <p class="ellipsis bodyTextTheme ng-isolate-scope" data-translate="appSettings" data-hide-parent="">Terms of Use</p>
</a>
```

I suspect the scope of the Side Menu is limited/isolated, so the fix that I am looking for does not exist. However, if you know of any possible workarounds, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can access some of these through your plugin code:

- Login : use `buildfire.auth.login` (https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Auth#buildfireauthloginoptions-callback)
- User Profile : use `buildfire.auth.openProfile` (https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Auth#buildfireauthopenprofileuserid)
- Home : use `buildfire.navigation.navigateHome` (https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationnavigatehome-)